# How to make notify-send appear at Settings/Notifications/Applications?

Tags: notification

I need to show the contents of `notify-send` on the lock screen for one of my scripts.
I see there are many applications at Settings/Notifications/Applications, but `notify-send` isn't there.
If it was, I would be able to let it show it's contents on lock screen as there is many options for each application, one being that.

But... it would be better to determine for each `notify-send` call, if it's contents should be shown on screen lock or not.

---

Anyway, an alternative to notify-send could work too.
Btw, this didn't work here: [Show notify-send content in Gnome's lockscreen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868474/show-notify-send-content-in-gnomes-lockscreen), nothing happened after running it.

---

ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I think that this is related somehow: youtube.com/watch?v=8KMqvAq6WYY

Answer (score 0):

This workaround worked fine here.
Has nothing to do with notify-send tho.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from gi.repository import Notify
from sys import argv

def notify(title):
  if Notify.init(title):
    n = Notify.Notification.new(title)
    n.show()

def main():
  notify(argv[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

but using `gdbus` is much better as we can "update" the notification: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75411/235896